# Visual Studio 2019 16.6.1 slow and irresponsive

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Since the last update, I have been experiencing tremendous problems with the performance of Visual Studio 2019 Community. (Unfortunately, I can't remember the previous working version)

- The startup takes 2-3 minutes (project selection)
- Loading a console project (Hello World) 5-10 minutes
- Keystrokes are sometimes only recognized after 2-3 seconds.
- Menus etc. take 10-15 seconds to open
- Minimize/Maximize the window takes 2-5 seconds

In this state, Visual Studio is unusable.

I have already tried the following:

- Virus protection deactivated (Bitdefender) -> Windows defender has taken over
- Virus protection completely deactivated
- Complete reinstallation of Visual Studio (without additional extensions)
- Windows Update checked for various updates that may slow down my PC
- Same update installed on my laptop (No performance problems here etc)

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Short Update: Same Problem with VS2017 (15.9.23)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might have been a problem with the Windows installation, after I reinstalled Windows, everything worked as usual.
Unfortunately I could not find out the reason for the problem.